# text editor to support uploading image from client rails app to rails api using ckeditor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ckeditor

I have created an CMS API and admin_client app with active resource in `rails 4.1.9`. Everything is working fine, Now I need a text_editor with image uploading feature in my admin_client app which get stored in CMS API. For that I decided to use "CKEditor" gem.

my question is

1. whether i can install the gem in both my API(for storing the image and for serving the image to user_client app) and admin_client app(for UI purpose).
2. Can i install the gem only in my API(for storing the image and for serving the image to user_client app). And use CKEditor plugin in my admin_client(for UI purpose).
3. Is there any other gem or options to achieve this ?

Please suggest me one of the options to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure as to the specifics of your request, but I do have experience with CKEditor, so I'll write some musings for you:

--

1. Install the gem where it's going to be deployed (the JS used)
2. Yes, but you have to match the models
3. CKEditor does it well with Paperclip - I'd stick with CKEditor if I were you.

---

[CKEditor's rails gem](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor#activerecord--paperclip) allows you to use `Paperclip` to upload the images. We had Paperclip installed anyway, so there was no problem. You may have to install it separately.

When you install Paperclip, you'll get [several models](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/tree/master/lib/generators/ckeditor/templates/active_record/paperclip/ckeditor):

- [`/ckeditor/asset.rb`](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/blob/master/lib/generators/ckeditor/templates/active_record/paperclip/ckeditor/asset.rb)
- [`/ckeditor/picture.rb`](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/blob/master/lib/generators/ckeditor/templates/active_record/paperclip/ckeditor/picture.rb)
- [`/ckeditor/attachment_file.rb`](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/blob/master/lib/generators/ckeditor/templates/active_record/paperclip/ckeditor/attachment_file.rb)

These are to be put into your backend app (I'm not sure whether that's your API or front-end view) (the [generator](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor#activerecord--paperclip) will do this). This will then give you the ability to save images from your CKEditor.

We have totally changed our models - so I can tell you it works out of the box, as well as if you customize. It's no problem if you want to keep them as they are when put onto your system.

Here's an example of one of our altered models (we have a central table for our assets):

[image]

--

The trick will be to make sure your CKEditor instance is able to send the correct assets to your API / backend app.

Since you've not published any code, I can only give you this broad information. If you post some specifics, I may be able to provide more detail if you need it

Comment: As per your suggestion i placed the models  in the api and installed the gem(without the model) in admin_client and changed the file_path  to api asset path.Now its working...... Thanks a lot for your great idea.......

Comment: No problem - if it worked, you should accept the answer so others can find it easier -- I see you did; glad it helped!